# Hypertext link on 1 internal page

Tags: angular

I would like to created two hyperlinks for `FACTURE NUMERO  000089352` and `FACTURE NUMERO  000089374`.

[image]

The patch is -> `..\src\app\views\portfolio\cash-account-statements`

In the file **cash-account-statements.component.html**. I have this for the field `Name of the operation`.

```
<td scope="col">
   <a (click)="showSignalDetails(l); false;" href="#" *ngIf="annexeHasaPage(l)">
   {{l.libelle}}
   </a>
   <span *ngIf="!annexeHasaPage(l)">
   {{l.libelle}} 
   </span>
</td>
```

When the user will click on `FACTURE NUMERO  000089352` for example, the file **annexe.component.html** must be executed.

The patch is ->  `..\src\app\views\portfolio\annexes`

How could I interact thes pages **cash-account-statements.component.html** and **annexe.component.html**.

Thanks

Comment: please elaborate in details, something is not clear. If possible use stackblitz

Comment: @Rajesh Kumar Swain: Here is an example -> [Stackblit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p8vqmp?file=src/app/app.component.ts)